# Who would have the android keystore password, alias and key password.

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-keystore

I'm updating an app that is already on the google play store. I have made changes to the app and I am trying to make a new signed apk so that I can publish the updated version of the app to the google developer console.

Whenever I go to make generate a signed apk, I get asked the following.

Key store path, key store password, key alias, and key password.

For the keystore path I am putting the path of the Filename.keystore file. For the key alias, it is already filled out. (I'm assuming that its the alias name)

So I have two spots left to fill out, which are key store password, and key password. Where do I obtain these things? Is it in the .keystore file?

Or are these things that I must obtain from the person who first created and published the application.

So any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Yup: `obtain from the person who first created and published the application.`

Comment: I kind of figured. Any other way around this? Maybe an unsigned apk? @MorrisonChang Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I obtain these things?

From your memory.

Or, from your password manager.

Or, if this is not your keystore, from the memory or password manager of whoever set up the keystore.

> Or are these things that I must obtain from the person who first created and published the application.

It would be whoever set up the keystore. Probably that was the person who first created and published the application, but not necessarily (e.g., somebody else on a development team).

Comment: I didn't create the project or the keystore file that I currently have. So I'm guessing that I must obtain this from the people who handed of the app to us. Well this is going to be fun. Thanks